# 'Is calculated' or 'are calculated'?

Tags: passive-voice, subject-verb-agreement

initailizer: something that I have defined in my algorithm to start the calculation.

What is correct `is calculated` or `are calculated`?

> In the next request the next  and  after next stops of the initailizer stop are found and the distance from the user's current location to these two points **is calculated**.

Comment: It applies to *the distance*. So, ***'is calculated'*** There are no two distances that could have been *then* 'are calculated...'

Answer (score 2):

You have a doubt because you have an impression that 'calculated' is in reference to *'two points'*. The calculation is done based on the distance. Distance is singular. So you should use 'is'.

If you want to use 'are calculated', it could be for the following kind of sentence:

> The **distances** from A to B and from B to C **are** calculated.

Answer (score 1):

If we simplify the construction after"and"

> the distance (from the user's current location to these two points) is calculated = the distance is calculated

where the phrase in the brackets serves as an attribute to the word "distance "you can clearly see that "is" refers to the word "distance ".